Azure Devops On Premise Server
I am using Azure Devops using classic Editor. My app is written in Asp.net core mvc. I chose asp.net core option from classic editor to build and release my app to the server. Here is snapshot of the same

I was able to install self hosted agent successfully in the on-prem server. But when I build the pipeline, I am getting below error message.

No agent found in pool OMIG-Dev which satisfies the following demand: visualstudio. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.144.0

Do I need to install VS in the server? Any help would be appreciated.
I tested this using my machine as build agent. I was able to successfully build and release the pipeline.


Do I need to install VS in the server?

Yes, you do need to install Visual Studio
I suggest you to install Visual Studio Build Tools, which is a lightweight installation package for compiling, building, and deploying applications without the Visual Studio IDE. You might need to install Visual Studio Test Agent as well (or, as an alternative, install it as a component of Visual Studio).
After the installation the following capabilities should be automatically added to the build agents:

msbuild
visualstudio
vstest

Note:

Download links can be found in Use command-line parameters to install, update, and manage Visual Studio.
After you install new software on a self-hosted agent, you must restart the agent for the new capability to show up
As an alternative to installing some tools in the server (e.g. Visual Studio Test Agent), consider using build tools installers tasks to install a tool or runtime on the fly just in time for your CI build, such as DeployVisualStudioTestAgent@2.


Thank you @Rui for your suggestion. I will follow this .
